# Proper way to manipulate data in object

Tags: c#

I created an object in one method, and my intention is to pass that object into another method and manipulate values of the objects properties in that method that it was passed to.

For example:

```
 void Method1()
{
Person person = new Person();

Method2(person);

Console.WriteLine("Person's age:" + person.age);

}

void Method2(Person p){

p.age = 24;

}
```

Now my question is, is this the proper way to program? Or is there a better way to do this keeping in mind Encapsulation?

Comment: You'd rather just have a method on the `Person` class which changes the age.

Comment: Did you mean "Proper way to manipulate data in *argument*" ?

Comment: No I mean is it proper to pass an object into another method and do stuff with it such as change values of its properties. Keeping in mind maintaining encapsulation.

Comment: There is no need to add a method to change a public property - that is just silly.  It could easily be argued that `Age` itself is a bad idea - usually you do not want to include data elements which are trivial to calculate.  A `BirthDate` property makes more sense mostly because there is no way to know if an age is up to date/accurate.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I didn't intend for the example to be taken literally as a real world example. What if that method did much more stuff instead of just changing one value? What I'm trying to ask is, is it proper to pass a object into a method and have that method change the data of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer to your question is "Yes," it is proper. It's definitely allowed, as you demonstrated, so (in theory) there is a need for it. On the other hand, a more appropriate answer might be "it depends." There's an old-school principle that says you should never allow objects (instances of classes) to ever be in an invalid state. When you have public setters and allow programmers to do whatever they want, they can create invalid states. For example, a programmer could set Age to -100 and that might cause serious problems when using Age in some other context. Constructors are one of the tools that you can use to ensure that your class is instantiated in a valid state. You can validate the constructor's inputs, set properties, and throw exceptions (or change values) as necessary to ensure a valid state. Likewise, you can have private/protected/internal setters on your properties so that relevant blocks of code can change those properties as needed and still prevent other blocks of code from changing them. That said, there are certainly valid use cases for public setters and, of course, those setters can have their own validation logic - in other words, you can take actions to ensure a valid state, even with public setters.

Sometimes you have a "plain 'ol C# object" (POCO) that is nothing more than a property bag (a collection of properties with public getters and setters - no *behavior* logic). This is handy for objects that represent data objects (they often mirror database tables or views), and they don't need a lot of validation because they are basically used for serialization in and out of JSON or some database engine. For example, you might have a class in your *domain* that's called Person. This class might have a complicated constructor and contain properties that only have public getters. It might contain validation logic, calculations, and other utilities relevant to the person you are attempting to model - you can choose to guard the validity of that Person object with extreme prejudice. Then, some piece of code somewhere might transform that *domain* person object to a property bag called PersonDto, which is used specifically for getting people in and out of your data store. A mapper of some sort is used to move your data from the POCO to the domain object and back again. That mapper can be a separate piece of code or you can build it into your classes (e.g., a ToDto() function or a ToPerson() function, or both). Of course, this is not the only way to handle these scenarios - it's just one example of how you might choose to do it.

So, back to "it depends." Good software design is harder than most people realize. You are going to make many, many mistakes, but it's a rewarding pursuit and worthy of study. You have to consider who is going to use your code, how much you trust them, and most importantly, what could go wrong. You want code that is easy to understand and use, easy to maintain, highly functional, and as simple as possible. There are core principles to OOP, and I recommend that you study them diligently. Try to wrap your brain around the differences between abstraction and encapsulation (the question you asked is really about encapsulation, which is a topic much larger than you might realize). Think about inheritance and polymorphism in your design. Avoid over-engineering when you can, and above all, always be prepared to say that you were wrong and that you need to re-think how you chose to do something. Getting it right the first time is nearly impossible (at least for me), but I recommend an approach of humility that asks, how could it be better? That said, it's okay to conclude that something is good enough. The true measure of success is working code. If it works, it works. But, always think about how others might break it or exploit it (e.g., think about a form that takes in credit card info - this is not a place to be lazy - that code must be tight and not open to exploitation).

I realize that this is a long-winded answer to your question, but I also remember others taking the time to give me guidance when I was starting out - I hope this stream of consciousness can be helpful. Coding is part science and part art; there are rules, but there's also room for your personal interpretation and style. Take the time to read up on the principles of OOP and practice them until you've internalized them - every little coding project is an opportunity to improve - and eventually, you'll write a piece of code that is not only functional, but elegant.

There are many great sources for information on these principles and you might be shocked at how many of them there are. PluralSight has some good, relevant courses if you can justify the expense. There are many books on these subjects, and many web pages discussing these principles. Here's one chosen at random: https://hackernoon.com/10-oop-design-principles-every-programmer-should-know-f187436caf65

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer. I have definitely learned a lot from reading it. And yes I love how programming is also an art. As a creative person I am falling in love with the creative aspect of programming, but I am also someone that want's to do things properly and understand exactly what I'm doing. Again thank you so much and I will read up more on OOP principles.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there can be valid reasons for modifying an object via some external method, or by having the object modify itself through its own methods. You may even use some combination of the two.

- In the case of some external method modifying an object, I think a creational design pattern like the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is a perfect example

  - The Builder pattern involves some object you'd like to represent (the `Person` class in your case) and an object that actually performs the act of building the desired representation (maybe a `PersonBuilder` class)

    - This pattern is ideal when the data you want to represent involves more complexity to calculate
- In the case of some object modifying itself through its own methods, I think of objects/classes where certain data should be internal to that class, and it exposes certain properties (potentially through [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields)) and methods to interact with that data

  - For example, you might have a `Counter` class that manages a count internally with certain rules that you wouldn't want other classes to violate, so you would need to manage that logic in the class and only expose certain interactions that are safe

```
public class Counter
{
    private int _count = 0;

    public Counter() {}

    public int Count
    {
        // The count can only be retrieved, not modified directly
        get { return _count; }
    }

    // We only allow interaction with our internal count variable through controlled means
    public void Increment()
    {
        ++_count;

        // We have special logic that we maintain in the Counter class and we don't want to violate it
        if (_count > 100) _count = 0;
    }
}
```

Having said all of that, the lame answer is that it depends on the problem you are solving; however, there are definitely patterns and guidelines you can use to help you determine the 'right tool for the job'. I recommend looking into [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), and the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) to give you a common set of guidelines that C# developers typically follow.